# How to Transfer app ids from one account to another

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to transfer app ids owned by one FB account to another?

Answer (score 14):

Yes this works perfectly.

1. Go to your FB app -> goto Roles, assign a Facebook friend as an administrator.
2. Ask him to accept the request and become an admin. (He has to add his account as a developer account, if not already a dev).
3. Now he goes to the App Dashboard and can see the app there. Can access the entire app. Good to go!!!

The primary administrator of the app can even delete the app from his account. Nothing happens to the transferred app

Answer (score 1):

I didn't do this before, but try to add a friend as administrator and then delete the original administrator from the app.

Maybe your friend has to have the right to be an administrator, that is he has to be uniquely  identified by Facebook as it works in your country.